# How do I set the listener() setting for external connection in Casablanca?

Tags: c++, casablanca

This code is accessible at 127.0.0.1.

**"http_listener listener("http://localhost:13654");"**

But... ...I don't know how to set up to connect from the outside.

I tried (0.0.0.0) but failed.

**http_listener listener("http://0.0.0.0:13654");**

How do I do that?

P.S
It is a server that is plugged into a single LAN and has ssh connection from outside.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cpprest/http_listener.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::experimental::listener;

int main(){
    http_listener listener("http://localhost:13654");

    listener.open().then([&listener](){cout << (U("\n start!!\n"));}).wait();
    listener.support(methods::GET, [](http_request req){
            req.reply(status_codes::OK, U("hello wordl"));
            });
    while(true);

    listener.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect from the outside try

```
http_listener listener("http://*:13654");
```

and remember to 'allow' your port for incoming connections in your firewall